# Check for duplicate row in database for a particular id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to check if my database table 'api_transactions' has duplicate value in coloumn 'ref_no' for a particular coloumn 'id' and also id here  is not unique.

```
|id|ref_no|

|0 |123456|

|0 |164656|

|0 |124446|

|1 |123456|

|1 |123656|
```

I want to check if id=1 has duplicate ref_no.How is it possible to do in codeigniter.
I searched and found the query for checking duplicate value of row in a table,but couldnt find a solution for what I have mentioned.Please help me out

Comment: I'm more confused by this than anything. Codeigniter aside, from a database pov, how you can you have three entries with `id = 0`, and two entries with `id = 1`?? That defeats the purpose of an id column.

Comment: This is an example I have given.I have clearly mentioned here that id is duplicate for this particular question,doesnt mean that its my database identifier.

Comment: then why name the column id.. that is confusing

Comment: @mituw16 There wouldnt have been a confusion if you clearly read the question

Answer (score 1):

The following query will get you a list of all duplicate (`id, ref_no`) pairs in your table.

```
SELECT id, ref_no, COUNT(*)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY id, ref_no
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To do this using the [active record class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) you would do

```
$this->db->select('id')
    ->select('ref_no')
    ->select('count(*)')
    ->from('myTable')
    ->group_by(array('id', 'ref_no'))
    ->having('count(*) > 1');
```